# AppHarbor MySql Yocto connection error

Tags: mysql, appharbor

My AppHarbor Web Instance uses the free MySql Yocto 20 MB plan, off late I'm seeing "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts". Is this because the database used up the free 20 MB or is MySql really down right now, I am not able to figure it out.

Is there any straight forward way of finding the curent database memory size that would be proportional to the plans published w.r.t MySql AddOn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had problems with our MySQL service in connection with a big Amazon Web Services outage. The MySQL service should be restored now, at least to read-only mode. We're tracking the situation closely.

The error you're seeing is unlikely to be related to database size issues.

Comment: Thats way too bad and scary. I am afraid that I do not see any information regarding the outage on the AppHarbor blog too, it would be great if you can keep track of the issue like the one [Heroku](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/151) has.

Comment: Just to complete the loop, what error would we get if the database allotted size is used up like the 20 MB free plan or does it simply not allow us to connect.

Comment: We're working on a Heroku-like status page and we'll be posting a post-mortem tomorrow. We're sorry you had a bad experience with this and we recommend you follow our twitter feed for service status updates.